# Can I mount a rolled poster to a mat? If so, how?

Tags: framing

I have a rolled poster that is very fragile and I don’t want to potentially crease it. I also can’t use heat or water as its sharpie signed. It’s not super badly rolled but it’s certainly not flat.

So two questions, can I mount it to a mat in the current situation or do I need to flatten it perfectly? And if so, how do I mount it? I’m afraid any kind of tape may permanently damage it.

Comment: You only need to flatten it perfectly *while* you mount it to a mat. A picture will likely help, and more information on the mat, especially the material.

Comment: Is "mounting to a mat" the only option you've considered? Are you open to other options, or have you ruled them out?

Comment: @AllisonC what are other options? I don't want to linen back it, or dry mount it.

Comment: You could have it professionally framed under glass (without mounting), using a frame shop with experience handling delicate items.

Comment: But the art would have a large propensity to stick to the glass, especially with a delicate signature that could easily wear away.

Comment: It really sounds like you're starting from a point of zero knowledge; it's incredibly rare (largely unheard of) that a frame shop would frame *anything* directly touching the glass. I would *strongly* recommend talking to a professional shop about how to handle this, instead of trying to do it yourself.

Comment: Its too late to do that lol I already framed it. But also how would I mount it under glass without mounting and without it touching the glass?

Comment: It is certainly not "too late" unless you damaged or destroyed the poster with your own efforts. Again, please consult with a professional, as your lack of knowledge of framing is a far greater threat to damaging your item than anything they would do.

Comment: How would they mount it without touching glass and without a matt? Spacers are also known to cause damage to art as they can be pressed into the paper. I think having it directly mounted to the acrylic (not glass) is the best way to prevent damage.

Comment: The fact that you keep repeating "how would they mount it without touching the glass" is *exactly* why I keep telling you to go to a professional. Gluing it to a mat board (which is intended to go *in front of* the image *to help separate it from the glass*) will do *far* more damage than letting a professional handle it with archival, non-damaging processes and materials.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to dry-mount it? And I assume you intend to glue it to a backing board (and not a mat in the sense of a passe-partout)? If that is the case, it's even easier to not have it touch the glass. Also, again, what material is the poster made of?

Comment: @AllisonC I keep repeating it because you keep telling me this is what they’re gonna do without telling me how they’re gonna do it like it’s some kinda magic. I never once mentioned gluing it to a mat board. The only options for not having it touch the glass are matting which won’t fit in an exact size frame, spacing which can cause damage as it presses on part of the print and dry mounting which is definitely not archival.

Comment: @Joachim it’s made of paper. I don’t want to dry mount it because that is irreversible. I never said I was gonna glue it to a backing board either.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. You wrote originally that you want to mount it to a mat, but how did you envision that without adhering the poster to something, using spacers or a mat, or have it touch the glass? And by "paper" I guess you mean the typical, glossy film poster material? Note also that there are reversible archival ways to dry-mount.

Comment: @ajgrinds again, those are *not* the "only options," just the only ones you personally, as someone who doesn't know much about framing, can think of. A professional framer will construct a frame for you if a standard one doesn't fit. They'll mount it in ways that don't damage the image. Or do you think every piece in a museum was "destroyed" by "non-archival" processes?

Answer (score -1):

I would glue it on a wood pannel (multiplex), because else I'm afraid it won't stay good (a mat will extend and shrink a lot with humidity)... To glue it, use for example upholsterer's glue, but it also depends on the kind of paper. I would try on a little corner before.

Comment: Wood also expands and shrinks with humidity, and upholsterer's glue sounds like a great way to do significant damage to the item.

Comment: Best is just to buy a good frame !